# В барплоте легенда накладывается на график,

Tags: r

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] к тому же хотелось бы в легенде уточнить на какой вопрос она отвечает, а именно в моем случае "Удовлетворенность работой".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ознакомьтесь, пожалуйста: [mcve]

Comment: 1. текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. 2. https://stackoverflow.com/q/3932038/4827341 3. вообще лучше, конечно, использовать ggplot.

Comment: хорошо,спасибо!